# Slow and Stuttery WPF Grid Scrolling when loaded with large amounts of data (40 columns, 2000 rows)

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

In a nutshell we're unable to get reasonable scrolling performance from any kind of WPF grid/items control when loaded with heavy amounts of pure data.

We've created a static independent prototype using the DevExpress WPF grid and uploaded it here:

http://jump.fm/QOTDL

We've also tried with the Infragistics and Xceed grid, and the problem is the same.

It seems like WPF simply cannot cope with reasonably large data grids displaying lots of data as far as providing a smooth user experience goes. Even without any kind of databinding, simply providing static data (~40 columns wide, 2000 rows), brings the scrolling to a crawl. At the lowest levels, the profiler seems to indicate an excessive amount of "Measure" occuring in addition to lots of garbage collection which could be the cause of the irregular stutter.

The code in the prototype can easily be replaced to work with other grids. If anyone out there is able to produce a smooth scrolling experience in the scenario given *especially* in cases where data is grouped at multiple levels and is densely packed, please let us know, we'd be very interested in hearing from you.

**Additional details:**

We're creating our 2000 objects (with ~40 properties each), and assigning them to the grid's datasource property.

Each of our objects is represented as a class similar to below:

```
public class RowViewModel
{
    public double AskAsw { get; set; }
    public string AskBmkName { get; set; }
    public double AskBmkPrice { get; set; }
    public double AskBmkSprd { get; set; }
    ... and so on
}
```

These are created and are added to a collection/list like so:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            _rowViewModels.Add(new RowViewModel(i));
        }
```

And then bound to the datagrid. Very straightforward:

```
        gridControl.DataSource = _rowViewModels;
```

This results in a datagrid displaying this information. We made the font smaller (10px, at user's request), and autosize and group the columns. The result ends up looking similar to this:

http://i54.tinypic.com/21jt11t.png

And scrolling is very stuttery/slow. Let us know if you have any thoughts.

Comment: How are you filling the grid ? Using databinding, or manually ? What kind of data source is it ? Please provide more details, because I doubt anybody's going to download the project file...

Comment: Is there a way you can specifiy the data panel in these grids, if so you need to look at putting in a VirtualizingStackPanel. It is specifically designed to handle large data sets by deferring the creating of UI elements until needed

Comment: @Thomas - thanks for the suggestions, I've added more detail to the post at the end.

Comment: @benPearce - the grids (whether the DevExpress, Infragistics or Xceed ones) are quite opaque in terms of being able to set these properties - the idea being that the grid developers have already implemented and optimized for things such as Virtualization. DevExpress specifically have no option to turn off vertical virtualization (i.e. it's on by default). Interestingly you can turn off horizontal virtualization and this seems to make side-scrolling faster as it's perhaps already calculated the visual tree for each row that way - it's the on-the-fly rendering that seems to be the bottleneck.

Comment: just tried ur upload but replaced the grid with Xceed. Seems to work fine for me. Did not bother changing the implementation for Autofit/GoupByNotes/ExpandAll. Group by is natively supported and appears to work well. No i dont work for Xceed, just we use that in our apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Data Grid that comes with .NET 40 works just fine for well over that. Tested with 200 columns and 50K rows (mix of int32, double, strings and custom class displays.

There are flags to turn on row and column virtualizations. Remember though that if you are doing grouping, that kills row virtualization.

I get around that by using my own drill down - two table - user control to get grouping functionality. Not great but sufficient for my needs.